# Changes to classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I've just been asked to look after some classic asp code, currently running on IIS6, I'm on IIS7...and the existing code is throwing up a few errors I'm not sure I'd expect.  Has anything changed in the way it should behave/is there a way to make it behave like it used to so I can fix these issues as it gets rebuilt?

The first is this:

```
    If NOT ISNULL(fieldforfiltering) then

    fieldforfiltering = TRIM(fieldforfiltering)

    convertbackfield = Replace(fieldforfiltering, "&#34;", chr(34))

            .....

    End If
```

This is complaining that fieldforfiltering is null on the 3rd line.  This I would expect from my C# life as the whole body of the if is not enclosed, so only the first line would get run (although there is an End If, so I'd sort of expect that to work...).  However, it's working on IIS6, just not IIS7.

The second is a Cint issue

```
    totcat = rs("totcat")       
    totalpage = totcat / 50
```

...throws a Type Mismatch error on the second line.  If I change it to

```
    totalpage = CInt(totcat) / 50
```

...it's fine.  Again, I sort of know why - but why would that work on IIS6 and not IIS7?

I'd like to get it working as it is (as it clearly does work) and then go through and fix these over the coming months...it's too big a job to do it in one go.

Comment: It's worth noting I haven't worked on classic asp for a good few years, so I've probably missed any changes to asp that may have caused this...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running with different options: `Option Strict On` vs `Option Strict Off`, for example.